# How to export Favorite list of tables in phpmyadmin and import back when needed?

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, drop-table

**Problem:**

Installing wordpress plugins to test their effectiveness, sometimes creates additional tables on database. After testing some plugins, it becomes difficult to quickly identify and delete not needed tables created by them.

**What I want:**

I want to add my needed tables to phpmyadmin's favorite list so that I can quickly identify newly created tables (tables without yellow star) so that I can drop those tables easily.

**Question:**

Is there a way to make phpmyadmin remember that favorite list without enabling **phpMyAdmin configuration storage**?

Or is there any other method that makes it easy to identify newly generated tables from old tables?

Answer (score 0):

Using the phpMyAdmin Configuration Storage is really the only way to enable and manage the favorite tables. Is there some reason you don't want to configure it? You can set it up in another database or the same database or a handful of other ways meant to make it easy for all sorts of situations (shared hosting, limited rights, etc) so hopefully there's a solution that works for you. If not, there may be some other tool that helps you track changes.

Comment: Thank you for replay. The only reason that I'm not interested to use "PhpMyAdmin configuration storage" is that I use shared host and I have not full access to server configuration. By the way, I'm almost new to WordPress and I'm not a coding geek. **Is it possible to enable "PhpMyAdmin configuration storage" in a shared host with cPanel?** I used **Adminer.php** but it has not favorite tables feature. **Isn't there any plugin or php script that can mark list of tables or add virtually to a group?**